# Chrome Vulnerability Issue

Tags: windows, debuggers, c++, exploit, debugging-symbols

My fuzzer recently crashed chrome and dumped what appears to be an exploitable vulnerability. I'm having an issue debugging it, as the referenced source appears incompatible with the version of chrome im running:

Chrome v. 41.0.2272.89 m
The callstack is referencing allocator_shim.cc
     `c:\b\build\slave\win\build\src\base\allocator\allocator_shim.cc`

The issue is that for the most recent source I've pulled, there's only
    `allocator_shim_win.cc`

Browsing Chromium source online also only has the newer
    `allocator_shim_win.cc`
instead of
    `allocator_shim.cc`

Why is my version of Chrome referencing/using old source (symbols/metadata) when it's supposed to be up to date?

Comment: Chrome != Chromium. [Google makes several changes to the Chromium code base before building Chrome.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29#Differences_from_Google_Chrome) This may be one of the changes.

Comment: Wow...youre a lifesaver.
Stupid question of the day (and I would appreciate it if you don't mind answering here, i'm not used to Google's revision controlled source):

How would I pull the chrome source that my version uses only, because I have the bleeding-edge git release of Chromium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome != Chromium. [Google makes several changes to the Chromium code base before building Chrome.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29#Differences_from_Google_Chrome) This may be one of the changes.

Nonetheless, the snapshot for the 41.0.2272.89 version of Chromium can be found here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/41.0.2272.89

You can see in https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/41.0.2272.89/base/allocator/ that there's no `allocator_shim.cc` file, which may suggest that the callstack artifact is from a change made by Google for Chrome. Alternatively, it could suggest that the standard build process "renames" `allocator_shim_win.cc` to `allocator_shim.cc` at build-time, in which case this might not be because of changes made by Google.